# Firebase database bandwidth usage when read with Query

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using Firebase in my android app, and I've noticed that the app use a lot of bandwidth.
I execute only read in the lower nodes childs like stated in the best practise to save bandwidth.

If I execute a query like this:

```
Query queryRef = firebaseRef.orderByChild("internalKey").equalTo(false);
queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
           ...
```

In the database bandwidth usage are counted all the child node or only those with internalKey = false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bandwidth counts the amount of data that you upload and download. It's really as simple as that.

If you have [defined an index](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html) on `internalKey`, then Firebase will filter the data on its servers and return only the elements matching the condition.

However, if you don't have an index on `internalKey`, all the data will be downloaded to the client and the client will then do the filtering. You should also see a warning about that in logcat iirc.

When you see large bandwidth usage, I recommend enabling debug logging (`Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG)`) and checking if the traffic in logcat matches your expectation.

Comment: Yes, I have an index on the key. The docs doesn't specify that information. There is only stated that the index is used for performances. Thanks! I will try what you have suggested.