# Should I use .indexOn in Firebase Realtime Database Rules if I read the database with Swift client libraries?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am reading the docs and I wonder if I should add `.indexOn` in the JSON tree under Rules in RealTime Database in order to improve the performance of the queries for child `TimeStampBookingDate`
The data will be read by the client(mobile app) using firebase Swift library.
I am a confused since in the docs it reads that:
"The realtime client libraries can execute ad-hoc queries without specifying indexes."
My Database is structured in this way

```
blvc-72e18
    Users
       2s8uH7sDwGbRdYwmXpGrRngmnUV2
         cus_AQVJTpFX2LdkzL
             282579602
               BookingAmount: "63"
                 TimeStampBookingDate: "1491654600"
```

In order to improve query performance at child key    `TimeStampBookingDate`, should I edit the default rules in firebase as follows?

```
{
 "rules": {
       ".read": "auth != null",
       ".write": "auth != null"
       "Users": {
       ".indexOn":"TimeStampBookingDate"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you add the .indexOn? You can certainly continue to read that node without it, however it significantly improves performance as the node count grows in size.

Comment: Definitely add the index.  This answer, from a Firebase team member, explains that an index significantly reduces the size of the downloaded data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35442993/4815718

Comment: @Jay should I insert .indexOn above this line  `".read": "auth != null",`?

Comment: It depends. In the rules provided, any authenticated user can read/write any node in the database (which may be a tad insecure). .indexOn is generally added to direct decedents of the nodes being queryed - so if you have a users node with /users/uid_0/name, /users/uid_1/name the .indexOn would be by *name*. However, your structure will not allow a query on TimeStampBookDate because it's too deep, so indexing on that would not have any effect. You may want to denormalize your structure and take a look at [Index Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)